How to get the path of invoking file from a to-be-imported file in Python?
Assume that there is a file named a.py with the following content:
import sys
sys.path.append("path")
import b

Now, there is a directory named path in the same directory as a.py. My goal is to get the path of a.py. How can it be achieved?
import os
print (os.path.realpath(__file__))

When I execute a.py from an arbitrary directory, I get the path of b.py, instead of the one of a.py. Of course, this behaviour is normal, but how can it be changed?

You can capture the name of a.py from the arguments passed to the Python invocation. You can then use os.path to get the full path details:
print(F"Argv0: {sys.argv[0]}")         # print the name
print(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))   # and the full path

On my system this produces the following output:
Argv0: a.py
C:\Users\oldboy\source\repos\a.py


Great answer! I would upvote it if I had enough reputation to perform that-

That's OK, You accepted it which is actually better than upvoting. Thank you.

In the file being imported, you can get the first caller frame in the call stack that does not start with < (which denotes an internal module) to extract the filename from its code object:
import sys

frame = sys._getframe(1)
while (filename := frame.f_code.co_filename).startswith('<'):
    frame = frame.f_back
print(filename)

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/ThirstyKaleidoscopicSdk#path/b.py
